# Simple Rspec test fails - for what reason?

Tags: ruby, rspec, functional-testing

Coding one of my first `rspec` tests. `headers == nil` prints `true`, but the next test line `headers should be_nil` fails. Why?

```
require 'net/http'

$url_arr = []
$url_arr << ...
$url_arr << ...
$url_arr << ...

module NetHelpers
    def get_headers(uri)
        Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse(uri)).get_fields('Set-Cookie')
    end
end

describe "new script" do
    include NetHelpers

    $url_arr.each do |uri|
        it "should not return cookies" do
            headers = get_headers(uri)
            p "==========> #{headers == nil}"
            headers should be_nil
        end
    end
end
```

Also, the output is

> got: "new script" (using ==)

Why *"new script"* is printed, while `headers` really contains `nil`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
headers.should be_nil
```

instead.

Comment: Thanks - it works! But (the second part of my question) why (in my case) the primary versions's output contains `new script...`? Tried to print `headers` - thought it's kinda known name, but got an `undefined` error.

Comment: The output of what? I think your question is missing the code relevant to that part.

Comment: The output of the wrong line (containing `should` without a dot) - it contains `new script` (which is the `describe` title). Does the question sound clear enough?

Comment: if you use "should" without attaching it to an object, it seems like it outputs the name of the test section, which is "new script" (in the describe line). Just a guess.